# Oracle PHP return columns from multiple tables gives index error

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I am using oracle 19c with php 7.4.6 and I know how to retrieve columns from a select query using only one table without any tables.

However, when I try a query that have select joins on say 4 tables, I have a problem with it using PHP where is says undefined index but when running the query using a client, it was fine.

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: cat_breed in X:.....

why us cat_breed undefined? The dog columns were fine.

For example, my query is:

```php
$thequery = 'SELECT dog_breed, dog_ancestor, dog_dna, cat_breed, cat_ancestor, cat_dna, bird_breed, bird_ancestor, bird_dna, fish_breed, fish_ancestor, fish_dna FROM dogs, cats, birds, fish where dog_breed = :thebreedid';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $thequery);
$the_breed = '1234567';
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':thebreedid', $the_breed);
oci_execute($stid);

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))  != false) {
            echo "<tr>\n";
            echo "<td>" . $row['dog_breed'] ."</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['dog_ancestor'] ."</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['dog_dna'] ."</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cat_breed'] ."</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['bird_breed'] ."</td>";
            echo "</tr>\n";
       }
    oci_close($conn);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `var_dump($row)` shows what?

Comment: Your query seems _odd_. Why are you performing a [Cartesian join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) without any criteria?

Comment: the query is just an example ...

Comment: shows array of values using var_dump

Comment: it works using coldfusion, java, etc... but not in php..

Comment: So `$row` is multi-dimensional? If so you need to iterate over that. That is strange though. From documentation shouldn't be, I haven't used oracle/this driver so have no real knowledge. If you could add the `var_dump` return that should help us assist you. The issue is the index names and they likely are different, maybe with an alias on them, or something else.

Comment: how do i iterate over them?

Comment: `foreach` or `for()` with a `count` of the array size.

Comment: okay.. I will try that

Comment: NOPE... same error

Comment: array(24) { ["USER_USER_ID"]=> string(8) "12345678" ["USER_KEY_ID"]=> string(8) "01011935" ["USER_FIRST_NAME"]=> string(6) "Elvis" ["USER_LAST_NAME"]=> string(5) "Pressley" ["PPL_BIRTH_DATE"]=> string(9) "01-JAN-35" ["PPL_KEYID"]=> string(8) "01011935" ["TRANSACT_MCODE"]=> NULL ["TRANSACT_MTH"]=> string(2) "04" ["TRANSACT_YR"]=> string(4) "2020" ["TRANSACT_TCODE"]=> NULL ["TRANSACT_DI"]=> NULL ["TRANSACT_KEYID"]=> string(8) "01011935" ["TRANSACT_OTHERID"]=> NULL ["TRANSACT_OTHERPASS"]=> NULL ["TRANSACT_PHYS"]=> NULL ["TRANSACT_SCHID"]=> NULL ["TRANSACT_ACTDATE"]=> string(9) "20-MAR-20" ...

Comment: None of that data is in the query you provided. It's hard to help with pseudo code and data.

Comment: I figured it out and used a different way of doing it now.. it looks like the multiple table join is problematic ...

Comment: Might be useful to post as an answer if the issue is consistent. If it was a typo though can probably delete the question.